# Problema com (Sql Server) insufficient system memory in resource pool

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, sql-server

Estou com um problema em algumas consultas realizadas pelo sistema, analisei o código e não tem erro, mais o banco está me retornando à mensagem

> “There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to
>   run this query.”

Alguém sabe como consigo uma solução para este problema?

Tenho a versão do banco:

> SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY
>   ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')

Resposta:
11.0.5058.0 SP2 Standard Edition (64-bit)

Veja a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontrei uma solução:

Solução alternativa (Isso se aplica somente a clientes do Servidor Dedicado). 
Você deve ajustar a configuração de Memória Mínima do SQL Server para 500 MB ou mais. Embora isso possa fazer com que o módulo funcione corretamente, isso também pode reduzir o desempenho geral do site.

```
1 - Faça o login no seu servidor dedicado usando o Remote Desktop .
2 - Abra o Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio .
3 - No painel Explorador de Objetos, clique com o botão direito do mouse em (local) (SQL Server xx.xx.xxx) .
4 - Selecione Propriedades e clique em Memória .
5 - Em Opções de Memória do Servidor,  insira o valor que você deseja que a memória mínima do servidor seja definida.
Clique OK .
```

Comment: Até descartei minha resposta pois é o mesmo procedimento só que pelo [`sp_configure`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-configure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).